# How to pass parameters to hooks in python grequests

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, grequests

According the Requests documentation, event hooks can be added to .get() function.

```
requests.get('http://httpbin.org', hooks=dict(response=print_url))
def print_url(r, *args, **kwargs):
    print(r.url)
```

This is fine but how to set *args with custom parameters, for example, I want to pass some custom values to print_url(), how to set those in *args ? Something like this fails :

```
args = ("search_item", search_item)
rs = (grequests.get(u, hooks={'response': [parse_books],'args': [args]}) for u in urls)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot specify extra arguments to pass to a response hook. If you want extra information to be specified you should make a function that you call which then returns a function to be passed as a hook, e.g.,

```
def hook_factory(*factory_args, **factory_kwargs):
    def response_hook(response, *request_args, **request_kwargs):
        # use factory_kwargs
        # etc.
        return None # or the modified response
    return response_hook

grequests.get(u, hooks={'response': [hook_factory(search_item=search_item)]})
```

Comment: Though this method works sometimes, I see the following exception:AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'history'
<Greenlet at 0x10fe32230: <bound method AsyncRequest.send of <grequests.AsyncRequest object at 0x10fe59790>>(stream=False)> failed with AttributeError

Comment: @Ved if you have a new question you should ask a new question

Comment: My comment was not a question but an attempt to complete the discussion. Thanks for pointing out by the way

Comment: I have concerns that *factory_args wont be matching with parameters in request. At least it have not worked out in my implementation

Comment: @aryat you have a different use case so you need to make a new question

Answer (score 2):

the `response_hook` function has to return a response-object. the simplest workaround would be
to modify the respose object you get from the hook_factory calling the hook.

```
def response_hook(response, *request_args, **request_kwargs):
    # use factory_kwargs
    # etc.
    response.meta1='meta1' #add data 
    response.meta2='meta2'

    #etc.

    return response# or the modified response

return response_hook
```

hope this helps.