# Create List of URLs for grequest

Tags: python-2.7, asynchronous, python-requests, grequests

Having this multiple payloads dictionarys, how can one better create a list of formatted urls so grequest can itereate over ?

> payload_single:  {'search': '51 F ST SW,AUBURN KING 98001,WA,USA', 'app_code': 'xyz', 'app_id': 'xyz', 'lod': '9'}
>
> payload_single:  {'search': '55 F ST SW,AUBURN KING 98001,WA,USA', 'app_code': 'xyz', 'app_id': 'xyz', 'lod': '9'}

To be able to send requests via grequests iterating over URLS using the below code :

```
unsentrequests=(grequests.get(u, hooks = {'response' : do_something}) for u in urls) 
responses=grequests.map(unsentrequests)
```

For a single call to requests i would use this:

```
row = requests.get(url_single, params=payload_single)
```

**EDIT 1** @rebeling

```
    for url in urls:
        unsent_request.append(grequests.get(url_single,
                                        hooks={'response': resphandler()},
                                        params=url))

def resphandler():
    rs = grequests.map(unsent_request)

    for r in rs:
        print r
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25115151/how-to-pass-parameters-to-hooks-in-python-grequests

Comment: @rebeling thanks , but seems not to be what im searching for

Comment: What about my answer then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import grequests  

def do_something(response, *args, **kwargs):  
    print response  


payloads = [
    {'search': '51 F ST SW,AUBURN KING 98001,WA,USA', 'app_code': 'xyz', 'app_id': 'xyz', 'lod': '9'},
    {'search': '55 F ST SW,AUBURN KING 98001,WA,USA', 'app_code': 'xyz', 'app_id': 'xyz', 'lod': '9'}]

unsent_request = []
```

See grequests code [line 35](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests/blob/master/grequests.py): 
Accept same parameters as `Session.request` and some additional, so we use params as you would in requests.

```
for payload_single in payloads:
    unsent_request.append(grequests.get('http://www.google.com', 
                                        hooks={'response': do_something}, 
                                        params=payload_single))

print grequests.map(unsent_request)
```

Comment: it does seem to work , im just confuse now on how to see the json responses .     Im using EDIT:1 code but only seeing the server <Response 200> , any ideia

Comment: in requests its r.json() otherwise inspect it like this print dir(r)